# Board View at left and text view at rigth Landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my Landspace to look like this

[image]

but it looks like this  when I use a RelativeLayout

[image]

I also tried with LinearLayout, but it didn't work.
Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    tools:context="co.edu.unal.androidtic_tac_toe.AndroidTicTacToeActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<co.edu.BoardView
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/information"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="info"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Human: 0     Ties:0      Android:0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put layout of your 3x3 grid here. Or you create it in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<co.edu.BoardView
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```